# Finding smallest $x$ for $\gcd(50+x^2,4x+2)=6$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

> Suppose $\gcd(50+x^2,4x+2)=6$ What is the smallest positive integer that $x$ could be?

It seems that this could be solved with modular arithmetic, however I would be interested to see if there would be another way which wouldn't depend on using modular arithmetic. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Trial and error is quick enough here.

Comment: Observe: $4$ works, $1,2,3$ do not.

Comment: With Euclid's algorithm you can find all solutions.

Comment: As proposed above, trial and error is good enough. Just try $x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the second term $4x + 2$ is some multiple of $6$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $3 \mid 4 x + 2$, $x \equiv 1 \mod 3$. Since $2 \mid 50 + x^2$, $x$ is even.  The first even number $\equiv 1 \mod 3$ is $4$.
And that turns out to work.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\,\ 6=(a,b)=(a,b,6) = (a,b,2)(a,b,3) = 2\cdot 3$

Here $\ (50\!+\!x^2,4x\!+\!2,2)=(x^2,\,2)\ =\ 2\ \,\iff\:\!\  2\mid x,\ $ and
and $\ \ \,(50\!+\!x^2,4x\!+\!2,3^{\phantom{|^{|^|}}}\!\!\!\!) = \underbrace{(x^2\!-\!1,x\!-\!1,3)}_{\textstyle (x\!-\!1,3)}\!\!\iff\! 3\mid x\!-\!1$

using $\,(a,b,n) = (a\bmod n,\, b\bmod n,\,n) =$  Euclidean gcd reduction (for $\,x\!-\!1\mid x^2\!-\!1$ too)

Answer (score 0):

if $6\big|(x^2+50)(4x+2)$ then:

$$24\big|(4x^2+200)(4x+2)$$

$$4x^2+200=x(4x+2)+200-2x$$

$(200-2x)$ is the remainder of division of $4x^2+200$ by $(4x+2)$ and must be divisible by 24(or we may say $6|(x^2+50)(4x+2)$ can be reduced to $24|(200-2x) \ $), so we must have :

$$ 200-2x=24k \implies x=100-12k$$

To minimize $x$, we maximize $k$:

$k=9 \implies x=100-108=-8$ is not acceptable.

$k=8 \implies x=100-96=4$ is acceptable.

Comment: I don't get how the remainder must be divisible by 24.

Comment: @Anas A , Ibrahim, because I multiplied the phrase by 4.