# Compute $\gcd(13n+2,5n-1)$ by generalized Euclidean algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

My question is:

For an integer k, define $f(x) = gcd (13x + 2, 5x − 1)$, use GCD With Remainders to list all the elements in the set ${f(x): x ∈ Z}$.

I divided 13x+2 by 5x-1 first, and got a quotient of 13/5 and a remainder of 23/5. But I am confused because GCDWR only works for integers. Therefore, if I write the next step as $gcd (5x-1, 23/5)$, that would be violating the rules for GCDWR. Could anyone give me a hint on how to proceed in the correct way? Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd (a, a+b)$. Can you use that to show that $\gcd(13x+2, 5x-1) \mid n $ for some integer $n$?

Comment: Like you realized, you want to take away **integer** multiples of each other (instead of fractional parts). So, take away $ 2 \times (5x-1)$ from $13x+2$, and repeat the process.

Comment: Okay I kind of get it, so we can just use algebra with x and write                          gcd(5x-1,3x+4) = gcd(3x+4,2x-5) = gcd(2x-5,x+9) = gcd(x+9,-23) = gcd(x+9,23) right? That makes a lot more sense, thank you!

Comment: Yes, that's how you extend applying GCD to polynomials (and polynomials evaluated at integer values, which is this case).

Answer (score 3):

This gcd is computable *purely mechanically* by a slight generalization of the Euclidean algorithm which allows us to scale by integers $\,c\,$ coprime to the gcd during the modular reduction step, i.e.

**Lemma** $\, \ \ \quad\qquad\qquad\bbox[8px,border:1px solid #c00]{(a,b)\, = \,(a,\,cb\bmod a)\ \ \ {\rm if}\ \ \ (a,c) = 1}\qquad\qquad  $

which is true since $\,(a,c)= 1\,\Rightarrow\, (a,\,cb\bmod a) = (a,cb)  = (a,b)\ $ by Euclid. When computing the gcd of polynomials $\,f(x),g(x)$ with integer coef's, we can use such scalings to force the lead coef of the dividend to be divisible by the lead coef of the divisor, which enables the division to be performed with integer (vs. fraction) arithmetic. Let's do that in the example at hand.

$$\ \ \begin{align} (\color{#c00}5x\!-\!1,\, 13x\!+\!2) &= (5x\!-\!1,\,13\:\!(\color{#c00}{5x})+\color{#c00}5\cdot 2)\ \ \ \text{by Lemma: scale 2nd arg by $\,\rm\color{#c00}{c=5}$}\\[.2em]
 &= (\color{#0a0}5x\!-\!1,\,23)\ \ \ {\rm by}\ \ \color{#c00}{5x\equiv 1}\!\!\!\pmod{5x\!-\!1}\\[.2em]
 &= (x\!-\!14,\,23)\ \ \ \text{by Lemma: scale 1st arg by $\,\color{#0a0}{5^{-1}\!\equiv 14}\!\!\!\!\pmod{\!23}$}
 \end{align}\qquad$$

By $\,23\,$ prime, the gcd $= 23$ or $1$, when $\,23\mid x\!-\!14\,$ or not, resp.

**Remark** $ $ [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3387196/242) is another example done this way - which explains how it can be viewed as applying a more general Polynomial Division Algorithm where the divisor is *nonmonic* (i.e. lead coef $\neq 1$), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3671880/242) is another one.

There are [many ways](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/25395/242) to compute the modular inverse $\,1/5 = 5^{-1}\pmod{23},\,$ e.g.

$\bmod{23}\!:\,\ \color{#0a0}{\dfrac{1}5} \equiv \dfrac{5}{25}\equiv \dfrac{28}2\equiv \color{#0a0}{14}\ $ by [Gauss's Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/25395/242).