# Question Regarding GCD Proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm

I have a question about a proof involving greatest common divisors. A function $g(k) = \gcd(13k+2, 5k-1)$ is defined where $k$ is an integer. How do we find all the elements of $\{g(k) : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$?

So, the first thing I did was simplify using the division algorithm and it turns out $\gcd (13k+2, 5k-1) = \gcd(k+9, -23) = \gcd(k+9, 23)$.

It can be easily seen that $\gcd = 1$ and $23$ since $23$ is prime. So would all the elements in $\{g(k): k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ be $\{1, 23\}$? I used some numbers to try it out and it seems so.

Also, how do we prove if $b<a$ and that $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, then $\{k \in\mathbb{Z}: g(k)>1\} = \{k \in\mathbb{Z}: a \mid(k+b)\}$? To prove this I know if $g(k)>1$ then it is $23$. However, I'm stuck on $a\mid (k+b)$. I think there are $2$ cases, where $(k+b)$ is either positive or negative.

Comment: Part 1 --> (k+9,23) : I agree with your step by step analysis.  Part 2: counter example: a=9, b=3.

Comment: @user2661923 Thanks. But for part 2 I wanted to prove that there exists a and b such that the above statement is true.

Comment: Then choose $a = 3 = b.$

Comment: **Exact dupe** of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3881868/242) $4$ days ago, but can't close because the (correct) answer has no votes. If you wish to give a another (general) answer then please do so there in order to avoid dupe fragmentation.